# HTMLAgilityPack: C# how to add strings with tags using CreateNode

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to build HTML output with data that might contain HTML tags (simple ones, link  or 
).

If I add such a string to my HTML using CreateNode, some unwanted filtering happens. How can I fix this?

Example:

```
string myText = "<strong>Intro</strong><br />Some Explanation";
node.ParentNode.ReplaceChild(HtmlNode.CreateNode(myText, node);
```

In my resulting HTML, only the strong text is outputted, the rest is gone.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try using **InnerHtml** ?

```
string myText = "<strong>Intro</strong><br />Some Explanation";
node.ParentNode.InnerHtml = myText;
```

Comment: That works, but it complete replaces the complete node. As my example above was only an excerpt it is not suficient for me now. But thanks for the tip!

Comment: It seems that certain tags are left out for some reason: adding table tags is fine, adding an italic in a bold works fine, but only an italic does not, p is left out completely and so on. Could it be the case that all (or most ) formatting related tags are stripped?

Comment: I don't think so. Check that all your tags are properly closed.

Comment: My tags are closed properly, checked that over and over again :-( The bizarre part is this: if I start with a bold section, followed by a 'regular' section, only the bold section is displayed. If I use italic IN that bold section, the italics render fine...